# Перерегистрация сервиса WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при запуске сервиса WCF, если на той же машине запущен такой же сервис с таким же URI, то сначала закроется старый сервис, а потом откроется новый. Например, сервис запустят с другой учетной записи

Answer (score 1):

Каждый инстанс WCF слушает какой-то определённый порт, например 80, 8000, 8080 или какой-либо другой.

Если вы попытаетесь запустить вторую копию, не потушив первую, то получите ошибку "порт занят".

Поэтому если подобный механизм очень-очень нужен, то в принципе это возможно, но нужно перед стартом проверять не занят ли порт, а также иметь возможность отдать команду запущенному инстансу на закрытие.

Comment: Небольшая поправка. Занятый порт - это не проблема, потому что в WCF разные приложения могут слушать один и тот же порт. Проблема в том, что они пытаются слушать еще и один и тот же URL...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Никогда не задумывался о такой тонкости, знаю лишь, что когда случайно запускаешь ещё одну копию сервиса - то сразу получишь ругань на занятый порт. По крайней мере, я считал, что не могут два приложения слушать один и тот же порт. Выходит, что на уникальность проверяется сочетание url+порт, а не просто порт? Я думал, что сама ОС запрещает слушать один порт разным программам.

Comment: Это если винсокеты использовать. Но WCF использует не их... Если биндиться по http или net.tcp со включенным порт шарингом.